# how to replace first occurence of string using regex JS

Tags: javascript, regex, search, replace

I have an html code , I want to search for a specific string , and replace it with "X" char  , i want to do this in a way where i replace only the frist occurence and stop the process .  for exemple , in the above code , i'm searching for the word "Alger" (the word occured 2 times) , so the regex should only replace the first one

```
<p><meta charset=utf-8>Declaration-sur-lhonneur MOHAMED
</p>
<p >
<span class="Policepardfaut">Alger</span>
<span>Le</span>
<span>/07/2018  ALger </span>
</p>
```

Comment: what have you attempted to do? show your attempt

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = `ALGER Alger Alger`;

let outputCaseSensitive = input.replace('Alger', 'X');
let outputCaseInsensitive = input.replace(/alger/i, 'X');

console.log(outputCaseSensitive);
console.log(outputCaseInsensitive);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
let t = `<p><meta charset=utf-8>Declaration-sur-lhonneur MOHAMED
</p>
<p >
<span class="Policepardfaut">Alger</span>
<span>Le</span>
<span>/07/2018  ALger </span>
</p>`

let r=t.replace(/Alger/,'X')

console.log(r);
```